# Spring 4.x with Spring Integration 4.X ClassLoader issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-integration

I found the following on my SystemErr.

```
[10/11/15 10:12:27:905 BRST] 0000000c SystemErr     R SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[10/11/15 10:12:27:905 BRST] 0000000c SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/SPRING_INTEGRATION_NEW/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[10/11/15 10:12:27:906 BRST] 0000000c SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/SPRING_INTEGRATION_NEW/slf4j-simple-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Do you know which jar I have to let on the classloader for Spring and Spring Integration? logback or SLF4J , as far I remember the jars were copied using mvn dependency plugin.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Need to have more context, of course. E.g. how do you build and pack your application? Do you use Spring Boot? And so on.

But from big height you just should **exclude** on of those `StaticLoggerBinder` dependency. In my opinion it would be better to remove `slf4j-simple`. It doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Hi Artem, "no, in fact i have to run my application on WebSphere, and i am not aware if i can use spring boot inside a J2EE (Jee5) container" . My build is a simple maven build with just the compiler and the resources plugins. Do you think that Spring Boot (if it can be used inside a J2EE container), is usefull to manage the Spring Application inside the container, so far the Spring Integration application is working very well, with no problems until now in a "old legacy container".

Comment: Well, first of all Spring Boot can live in the WAS very well, but yes: without embedded Tomcat. From other side there is no reason to introduce it here, if you should just figure out who pull the `slf4j-simple` dependency for you and just exclude it. Or exclude all logging deps from your app and just rely on the WAS one. Which really may bring some unexpected deps for you especially when your app will be deployed on the customer environment.